# Serialization and deserialization from clipboard (copy/paste)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add copy/paste feature to my WPF application. I have a DataGrid which I allowed to select an entire row. A row is an object of type AcquisitionParameters. The selection is ok, the copy to clipboard too. After copying to clipboard, I verify if the data has been well serialized and it is the case. But when I try to retrieve the object from clipboard, I am not able to deserialize it on its original format, but in a CSV format.

```
private void dataGridAcquisitions_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear();
   DataFormat format = System.Windows.DataFormats.GetDataFormat(typeof(AcquisitionParameters).FullName);

   System.Windows.IDataObject dataObj = new System.Windows.DataObject();
   dataObj.SetData(format.Name, (AcquisitionParameters)e.Item, false);
   System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, true);
   bool ispresent = dataObj.GetDataPresent(format.Name); // ok
   AcquisitionParameters parameters = dataObj.GetData(format.Name) as AcquisitionParameters; //ok
   if(parameters != null && ispresent)
   {
      //enter here
   }
}


private void dataGridAcquisitions_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.V && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
   {
      System.Windows.IDataObject dataObj = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject(); //type of AcquisitionParameters not available, only HTML, CSV, etc.
      string format = typeof(AcquisitionParameters).FullName;

      if(dataObj.GetDataPresent(format)) //false
      {
         AcquisitionParameters parameters = dataObj.GetData(format) as AcquisitionParameters;
         if(parameters != null)
         {
         }
      }            
   }
}
```

And the declaration of my AcquisitionParameters class

```
namespace App
{
   [Serializable]
   public class AcquisitionParameters
   {
      private double pulse;
      public double Pulse
      {
         get { return pulse; }
         set { pulse = value; }
      }

      private double range;
      public double Range
      {
         get { return range; }
         set { range = value; }
      }

      private double offset;
      public double Offset
      {
         get { return offset; }
         set { offset = value; }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the data from the `Clipboard` like this:

```
object data = Clipboard.GetData("AcquisitionParameters");
if (data != null) return (AcquisitionParameters)data;
return new AcquisitionParameters();
```

---

UPDATE >>>

If that doesn't help, then try setting the data like this:

```
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
dataObject.SetData("AcquisitionParameters", (AcquisitionParameters)e.Item, false);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

Comment: As I said, the clipboard does not contain any data of my custom format, only standard format in DataFormats... This code is not really different of mine sadly.

Comment: *This code is not really different of mine sadly*... no? Well mine works.

Comment: No doubt that it works in your conditions, the version I propose works under certain conditions : just after data is copied into clipboard, but it fails when I try to retrieve it afterward with Ctrl+V...